# Appium: How to capture uploaded image from camera on the android emulator without using the gallery on the emulator

Tags: java, android-emulator, cucumber, appium, android-camera

I need to capture specific image by camera in app which I'm testing. Android emulator have some samplers, but I need inject specific photo and app doesn't let me use gallery. I'm using java 11, android version: 9